# Use the eval function on a multiindex column that contains a column level with timestamps

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(datetime(2020, 5, 17), "A1", "A"), 
                                  (datetime(2020, 5, 17), "B1", "B")])

data = [[5, 10], [2, 15], [6, 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
lst = [5, '*', 'datetime(2020, 5, 17).A1.A']

query = ''.join([f'df.{x}' if (isinstance(x, str) and '.' in x) else str(x)
                 for x in lst])

df[(key, 'N1', 'N')] = pd.eval(query)
```

But I cannot make it work as the first level of the column names is a type of timestamp.

Comment: Why do you always want to evaluate an expression? Maybe you can use Pandas to do it? `5 * df[('2020-05-17', 'A1', 'A')]`

Comment: I want to translate a formula written in excel to an equation in python: for example a*[Today, Outdoor, Hours] - [Today, Outdoor, free]

Comment: @Thanasis this is not at all an usual way to work with pandas. As you already had many questions of the kind, I suggest you try to go through a pandas tutorial. You should not think in terms of what you were doing with Excel ;)

Comment: I am not trying to replicate something from Excel to Python, I am just trying to use the Excel as UI.

Comment: Still, that sounds like a bad idea to me (just my 2 cents, I don't know your exact needs)